# I am Looking the change the Magento status wording "Processing" to "In Production"

Tags: magento

I need to change the status to say "In production".
This would be in a core file I presume and i do not know where to locate it.

Comment: in order status grid?

Answer (score 2):

Go in the backend to `System->Order Statuses` and edit the status `Processing`. You will see a  screen that allows you to add a different label for each store view you have.

Just fill in `In production` everywhere if that is what you need.
If you don't set a value for a specific store view, the default `Status Label` will be used.

Comment: yes marius. You are right. I was thinking that there is an another process to do this without touching the core files. This is the simplest way.

Comment: Perfect it should be like this